# Rendering Rails partial in an ajax success callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Trying to render a partial straight from the controller like this:

```
def show
  @show = ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render :partial => "some_partial" }
  end
end
```

Since the `$content` (below) is dynamic, I can't use the action's `show.js.erb` file to render the partial.
Instead I just want to return the HTML directly to the callback's `response` like this:

```
var $content = $(some_dynamic_selector);
$.ajax({
  url: '/show',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    $content.html(response);
  }
});
```

But this seems to return the `format.html`'s HTML from the server, and not the partial.

To get the partial's HTML, I have to add `dataType: 'script'`, but that tries to execute the response directly.

**Question:** Is there a way to handle a plain HTML response in the ajax success callback?

Comment: Is the partial you want to render variable, or always the same?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to pass the selector tag to the AJAX request and have your partial use that:

```
var $content = $(some_dynamic_selector);
$.ajax({
  url: '/show',
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'selector=mydiv', 
  success: function(response) {
    $content.html(response);
  }
});
```

And make it available in your controller:

```
def show
  @show = ...
  @selector = params[:selector]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render :partial => "some_partial" }
  end
end
```

...and use that in your show.js.erb file.

Try that out, it's a bit hacky, but it should work.